# yule walker equation

Tags: arima, autoregressive

Can you please explain me how by taking the expectations of both sides one arrives at the final equation?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] to elaborate. You can use math typesetting via Mathjax. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference We also have some related questions that you can find with a search: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=yule+walker+answers%3A1+score%3A1

Comment: y_t * y_(t - tau) = phi * y_(t - 1) * y_(t - tau) + epsilon_t * y_(t - tau)                                 → y_tau = phi * y_(tau - 1)                                                                                                  I am just really unclear how you get the second equation from the first

Comment: @Adriano I don't know if this is just loose notation but the last equation in your comment is wrong; there are no y's anywhere, that's a gamma. The last equation in the post is also wrong, it should be $\gamma(\tau)=\phi\gamma(\tau-1)$ (i.e. $\gamma(h)$ is the autocovariance *function* at lag $h$, there's no $\gamma$ *constant* involved). Does that clear up the confusion or is there something else?